# UbuntuOne API - Developing a Perl module to use it

Tags: perl, ubuntu-one-api

I'm developing a Perl module to work with the UbuntuOne's API.

1) I'm able to retrieve the Name, Consumer key, Consumer Secret, Token and Token secret values using the basic HTTP authentication and JSON parser.

2) With these data, the [api-doc](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/auth/otherplatforms) says that I should do a GET to *https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/sso-finished-so-get-tokens/*

I get:

> ok 0/20

**Anybody knows what it means?**

3) Finally, when I try to use the API I receive a HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED :-(

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours fighting with ubuntu one. Here are the answers:

1) 0/20 means 0 valid Tokens. Although the process is correct, UbuntuOne is not able to validate your conection to the API.

2) During the basic authentication, the parameters are:

- ws.op=authentication
- token_name=Ubuntu One @ something

Caution: The token_name should be exactly (capital letters, spaces, etc).

Comment: Ok, the first super-basic but functional module is ready at https://github.com/xpeco/UbuntuOne